# is it possible for two users to login at same time

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors

Hello Friends as i was thinking is it possible for two users to login at the same time in the same machine with multiple monitors can we do it or not and if we can please supply the handy information

Answer (score 2):

`Multiseat X` refers to a single machine that supports multiple concurrent users each with their own set of keyboards, mice, and monitors providing a traditional desktop experience to each user.

Check out this [document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX)